# Button Link did not redirect the page

Tags: html

When I click on exit button it will not redirect to another page.

```
<button  onClick="window.location='logout.php'">Exit</button>
```

I am doing above code but it will not work.

Comment: If that doesn't work, it means you have code elsewhere that's overriding it.

Comment: Clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/ExtVC/  what you think is your problem is not your problem.

Comment: Have you checked console tab for errors?

Comment: The code you show here has no problem. May be the problem is in other parts of your codes. Or may be your browser setting problem.

Answer (score 0):

it works in all browsers:

```
window.location.href = 'page';
```

use

```
 <button  onClick="javascript:window.location.href ='logout.php'">Exit</button>
```

If you want to change the page without reflecting it in the browser back history, you can do:

```
window.location.replace('Page');
 <button  onClick="javascript:window.location.replace('logout.php')">Exit</button>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is not an answer to the OP's question, since the code posted for review is totally fine.  You're offering alternatives that are irrelevant since whatever is causing the original code to not work is going to prevent your alternatives from working as well (most likely).

Comment: @GeniaS. you know OP's code is correct. but you don't know may be its a browser issue. if page path is correct and there is no other syntax issue then it should have worked. so i am suggesting OP a alternative so that it should not be restricted by browser. Thanks

Comment: @DeepSharma Oh, that was me who down-voted. Forgot to comment, I down-voted because of the reason that his code is correct. There is nothing wrong with it therefore there is no answer until they post other code that could be affecting this. Its good that you gave a little extra but still, this is not the answer.

Comment: @GeniaS. I can name a browser that behaves that way. Mosaic. ;)